# ErrorException in SessionGuard.php in Laravel 5.3 with Socialite (Facebook as provider)

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I got a Laravel project (v5.3) which needs a login with a custom form and with facebook connect.

So, I use Socialite and it's what I need, however, when I login for first time, the callback doesn't redirect to the view/url that I indicate, instead Laravel shows me the next Exception:

> ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 439:
>   Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 294 and defined

This is the code in my custom controller :

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try
    {
        $socialUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

    }catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }
        $user = User::where('facebook_id', $socialUser->getId())->first();

        if(!$user)
            User::create([
                'facebook_id' => $socialUser->getId(),
                'name' => $socialUser->getName(),
                'email' => $socialUser->getEmail(),
            ]);

            auth()->login($user);
            return redirect()->to('/home');              
}
```

So, I check my database and the record is there - Ok
...but I'm not in session - wrong
... if I login with facebook again (keeping the record in the database) I login successfully and the error is gone... Ok but at all...

If  I do:

```
dd($user)
```

I got a *null* value the first time
In the following times I got nothing...the $user var show in blank...

So I think is this line:

```
auth()->login($user);
```

And I tried

```
\Auth::login($user);
```

but it doesn't work too...

So, what's could be wrong, any configuration in my project?
This example I saw it in tutoriales with Laravel 5.3 so I don't understand what's going on :(

Thank you! And sorry for my english!
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
if(!$user)
        $user = User::create([
            'facebook_id' => $socialUser->getId(),
            'name' => $socialUser->getName(),
            'email' => $socialUser->getEmail(),
        ]);
```

I added `$user =` to your existing code. Because when you do `Model::create` it returns an object of type `Model`.

Comment: Yes! You're right! Now the login works! Thank you so much! :)